# How can I do a Fourier expansion for a waveform with uneven square pattern

Tags: fourier-transform

The pattern of the wave is as follows:

1. 0.0 - 0.5 => low,
2. 0.5 - 1.0 => high,
3. 1.0 - 2.0 => low,
4. 2.0 - 2.5 => high,
5. 2.5 - 4.0 => low,
6. 4.0 - 4.5 => high,
7. 4.5 - 6.5 => low,
8. 6.5 - 7.0 => high,

[image]

The pulses are equal but the time between different pulses increases as follows: 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0. This pattern repeats itself so that if we keep going the next iteration would look like this:

9. 7.0 - 7.5 => low,
10. 7.5 - 8.0 => high,
11. 8.0 - 9.0 => low,
12. 9.0 - 9.5 => high,
13. 9.5 - 11.0 => low,
14. 11.0 - 11.5 => high,
15. 11.5 - 13.5 => low,
16. 13.5 - 14.0 => high,

[image]

I'm a total noob when it comes to Math.

Comment: Why do you want the Fourier expansion? What would you use it for?

Comment: I want to use it to generate values for crea createPeriodicWave() in Java script

Comment: Then you don't need Fourier expansion. Just define the piecewise constant function on $0$ to $7$ and use a modulo operation to reduce to that case.

Comment: A little demo would really help. I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: @Somos can you help break this down a bit for me?

Comment: I see some folks would like to recommend alternative solutions, but certainly *asking* how to do a Fourier expansion is a valid question. Since you want to implement a generator *in software* you might look around in [Signal Processing SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) as well. However before asking there check for other Q&A that may already work for you and make sure to explain there what you are doing and what problem needs to be solved.

Comment: Just use basis functions that apply to the time interval $T=7$.  The coefficients will be trivial to compute, although not "pretty."  Inasmuch as you're developing a computer code to generate numerical results, the "ugly" form for the coefficients is not an issue.

Comment: @MutaiMwiti I have given one approach using Mathematica in my answer. It can be easily adapted to any other language.

Comment: The Fourier transform of that function is **guaranteed** to be very messy. It is not a periodic function, and it is not integrable on the real line, stay away from it.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro OP asked for Fourier **expansion** and the function **is** periodic with periodic with period 7. OP wrote "This pattern repeats itself ".

Comment: @Somos: Oh right, I misunderstood, thanks. Then the function is periodic.

Answer (score 1):

While not the Fourier expansion the OP asked for originally, here's an alternate approach which may
be what is actually wanted.

The following Mathematica code produces the output shown

```
f[x_] := With[{r = Mod[x,7]},
    Boole[.5<r<1||2<r<2.5||4<r<4.5||6.5<r<7]];
Plot[f[x], {x,-.5,14.5}, PlotRange->{-.1,1.1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graph plot]

Similar code can be easily written in any other language. Note that `Boole[x]` returns $1$ if $x$
is true and $0$ if $x$ is false.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a shot